# WPF MVVM creating tab Items programmatically with and new instance of the related view for every tab item

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabs

I have a TabControl in WPF that is bound to an ObservableCollection (OperationsTab), and in the ViewModel (below) I create new tabs as needed using the method below in VM. The method uses a factory to create a new instance of the TabItem view model and passes it to the content property of the created tab. I am using a TabViewModel that has a object property for content.

I created a DataTemplate to connect the view to the ViewModel as follows:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:PracticeOperationsViewModel}">
    <views:PracticeOperationsView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The View Model:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> OperationsTabs { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>();

private void PracticesLandingViewModel_OpenNewPracticeOperationsTabEvent( object? sender, UserArgsDTO e)
{
    if (OperationsTabs.Count <= 10)
    {
        TabViewModel practiceProfileTabViewModel = new();
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabName = e.TaxID.ToString();
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabCloseButtonVisible = "Visible";
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabNameVisible = "Visible";
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabIconVisible = "Collapsed";
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabMinWidth = 40;
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabMaxWidth = Double.NaN;
        var viewModelContent = _practiceOperationsViewModelFactory.CreateViewModel();
        viewModelContent.LoadPracticeProfile(e.TaxID);
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabContent = viewModelContent;
        OperationsTabs.Add(practiceProfileTabViewModel);
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when I create multiple TabItems (Parent TabItems) for different new instances of the underlying view models, they all have the same view using the DataTemplate so as I switch between the Parent TabItems, the views for all the Parent TabItems are connected to the single view. Each Parent TabItem has a Child TabControl, so to explain further; if I navigate to Parent TabItem2 and start working on Child TabItem3, then when I navigate to Parent TabItem1 it will auto navigate to Child TabItem3 in Parent TabItem1.

I think I need to create a new instance of the view every time we load a new tab, so I created a Form Factory to generate a new instance of the view when needed following [TimCorey's Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLR_D2IJE1M). I added the factory through the DI constructor injection and updated my method that creates the tabs to take a new instance of the view as follows:

```cs
private void PracticesLandingViewModel_OpenNewPracticeOperationsTabEvent( object? sender, UserArgsDTO e)
{
    if (OperationsTabs.Count <= 10)
    {
        TabViewModel practiceProfileTabViewModel = new();
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabName = e.TaxID.ToString();
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabCloseButtonVisible = "Visible";
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabNameVisible = "Visible";
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabIconVisible = "Collapsed";
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabMinWidth = 40;
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabMaxWidth = Double.NaN;
        var viewModelContent = _practiceOperationsViewModelFactory.CreateViewModel();
        viewModelContent.LoadPracticeProfile(e.TaxID);
        practiceProfileTabViewModel.TabContent = viewModelContent;

        var newPracticeOperationsWindow = _practiceOperationsViewFactory.Create();
        newPracticeOperationsWindow.DataContext = practiceProfileTabViewModel;

        OperationsTabs.Add(practiceProfileTabViewModel);
    }
}
```

however, it is not picking up a new instance of the view on creating a new Parent TabItem, it seems like the DataTemplate is defining the view and not the method.

I tried to remove the DataTemplate code to allow the method to determine the view for the viewmodel but that didn't work, what can I do to make this work as expected please??

Comment: You need to store the view state in the ViewModel. If the child tabindex is important, then store it in the ViewModel